# Can removing files from local directory after full commit and pushing?

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have fully pushed my changes in files from PC A through sourcetree, and relocated a few files and deleted a few from my local environment.

After a few hours, I tried to pull the changes I made from PC A from PC B, it doesn't work and it seems like same files form PC B has been deleted.

I have checked several times that the last commit from PC was to add codes, not to delete files.
I attached the state from source tree.
[source tree screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdZYM.png)

after that I can't make any changes on the same branch.

If I should not make any changes from local directory such as move / delete or the reason why I'm having such hard time, just let me know so I can no longer make the same mistakes.

sorry if this question sounds silly, I have just started my development career.
thanks in advance